# Choosing which fields appear in a modelform according to user

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Lets say I have a model like the following:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
   #has some fields
   doctor = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

So a patient model has a doctor that treats him. I also have model form

```
class PatientForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Patient
```

So all fields are included. Lets say now frontdesk(nonstaff) can create patients and has to asign a doctor on them. So PatientForm works cause the doctor field will appear normally. But a doctor can create a patient too, but when a doctor(staff user) creates a patient the doctor field must be filled automatically by the connected user and not rendered in the template. Something like:

```
if request.user.is_staff():
    form = #PatientForm_without_doctor_field
else:
    form = PatientForm()
```

Can it be done using the same PatientForm class? Is it better to have to different ModelForms (one with field included and one with doctor excluded) and use it accordingly? which is the best approach for that? Is it better to have a new model form with request.user in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `request.user` to form init in view:

```
def some_view(request):
     form = PatientForm(user=request.user)
```

and modify form fields according to user in form init after form creation:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser

class PatientForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Patient

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', AnonymousUser())
        super(PatientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user.is_staff():
            # hide field and set doctor to request.user
            self.fields['doctor'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
            self.fields['doctor'].initial = user
```

Comment: That is what i thought. Maybe there was a method to include or exclude field like self.exclude('doctor')

Comment: @Apostolos i think you can exclude field just by removing it from fields dict in form init method but in this case you need to override save method to pass `request.user` to your model `doctor` field...

Comment: So in the constructor del self.fields['dotor'] inside if user.is_staff right? But then I must manually set patients.doctor = request.user after saving the form with commit=False correct?

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit]** While initializing you can set the initial values based on a keyword argument:

```
class PatientForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, readonly_doctor=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if readonly_doctor is not None:
            self.fields['doctor'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['doctor'].initial = readonly_doctor

    class Meta:
        model=Patient
```

Then you can conditionally pass it:

```
if request.user.is_staff():
    form = PatientForm(readonly_doctor=request.user)
else:
    form = PatientForm()
```

Comment: Not getting it...Saving method is for commiting the form...I am talking about the step before that...The rendering.

Comment: Sorry, understood your question better now.

Comment: Sure but setting in the constructor is not enough. The user can tamper the form in the browser and submit a different value. Setting it to readonly makes sure that Django checks that the field is intact. Or you need to set it while saving it.

Comment: Yes..was thinking something like:pat = form.save(commit=False) pat.doctor = request.user  when user is_staff...But your method looks better i think